# Cordova Browser platform error

Tags: cordova, browser

I'm running Cordova on Windows 7 installing Chrome 38.0.
Android version works fine but I got following error on Browser platform.
Any idea?

(Cordova version:3.6.3-0.2.13 and Installed platforms: android 3.6.3, browser 3.5.2)

```
>cordova run browser
Running command: cmd "/s /c ""d:\***\platforms\browser\cordova\run.bat"""

events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: spawn ENOENT
    at errnoException (child_process.js:1001:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:792:34)
Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 8
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (C:\***\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\cordova\superspawn.js:135:23)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:756:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:823:5)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Alan my problem has been solved.
See: [“cordova run browser” reports error “Error: spawn ENOENT”](http://alanzhu.cn/blog/?p=64)

I just have to correct Chrome address in "`<my_path>\testapp\platforms\browser\cordova\run`" file.

Comment: Can you provide more details on how you ran it?

Comment: try ```cordova run browser```.

Answer (score -1):

The cordova tools call the Android ant script, and this error is usually because the ant script can't locate the android tools.

This usually happens after an upgrade, or after the project has been moved.

Try

```
$ cordova platform remove android
$ cordova platform add android
```

or delete the platforms/android directory and add the platform again.

Comment: As I said, my problem is with the **Browser** platform and not with Android. Android works fine.

Comment: my bad, misunderstood the problem